# Permission denied error when creating cache folder - Apache httpd

Tags: apache, apache2, httpd.conf, dispatcher

I am using Apache HTTPD with the Dispatcher module running on RHEL. 
The dispatcher works fine but it's unable to cache the file. On inspecting the logs I see the following error -

```
  Unable to create parent directory /var/www/html/bla/bla/static: Permission denied
```

My apache is running with the default user and usergroup - `apache`
[image]

I have also changed the ownership of my docroot (`/var/www/html`) to `apache`.

```
drwxrwxrwx.  20 apache apache  278 Jun 14 04:08 var
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? Please help!

Comment: What are the permissions of `/var/www/html/bla/bla/`

Comment: same as /var/www/html